# Действия над переменной

Tags: mysql

Скажите пожалуйста как "перечислять" действия на переменной?

```
SELECT (@str:=FROM_BASE64(Content), ..Какое-то действие над переменной..) FROM `Info` WHERE 1
```

Comment: если круглые скобки убрать, то при любой операции с переменной в следующем поле она будет иметь то значение, которое у нее было установлено в предыдущим и да ее можно изменить просто новым присвоением

Comment: @Mike спасибо, оформите красиво, я проголосую